# Android: in TabWidget, is there a way to get the view containing the tabs?

Tags: android, tabs, android-tabhost, tabwidget

Hi all
I'm trying to write a tab activity in which each of the tabs has a custom view for the indicator.
The view is inflated like so:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)
            context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE); 
        specIndicatorView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_indicator, null);

        indicatorIv = (ImageView)specIndicatorView.findViewById(R.id.indicatorImage);
        indicatorTv = (TextView)specIndicatorView.findViewById(R.id.indicatorText);

        indicatorIv.setImageDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(indicatorImageRes));
        indicatorTv.setText(indicatorTextRes);
```

The problem is that the layout parameters that are defined in the child view do not affect it and that is because I don't know how to pass in the parent view to the inflate method.

All I'm trying to do is have an image and some text where the image is aligned to the top and the text is aligned to the bottom of the indicator view but I also need some little tweaks that require me to use this indicator strategy.
I've looked at the source of the entire tab mechanism and could not figure out how to get the parent view, do you know how to do it?
do you have a better way to achieve what I need?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You said you looked through all the code for tabs; what was wrong with just calling [`getTabWidget()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/TabActivity.html#getTabWidget%28%29) in your activity?

Comment: Hi Yoni, as I said before, I require a "View" object and the tab widget is not that.
It is possible to call the getChildTabViewAt() method but there are 2 problems with that: a) I want to create the child tab with the view in it but getting the child tab view will only return it for a built tab, and b) this returns the content view only i think and not the bigger container view

Comment: I think I'm missing the point here. Just use `getTabWidget()` instead of `null` as the 2nd argument to the layout inflater if you want to use inflate a custom layout for a tab using tabSpec's `setIndicator` method. See the Google IO 2010 Scheduling app: http://code.google.com/p/iosched/source/browse/trunk/src/com/google/android/apps/iosched/ui/ScheduleActivity.java#147

Comment: I'm sorry, you are right, I was using getTabWidget().findViewById(android.R.id.tabs) but getTabWidget works as well, I missed the fact that the tab widget is a viewgroup as well...
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to access the `TabHost` from within one of the tab activities? If so, you should be able to get to the `TabHost` via [`getParent()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getParent%28%29) from the child activity.

Comment: I'm actually not looking to get the parent activity but rather the "View" object, furthermore, I'm inside of the TabActivity when trying to do it and send it to the inflater

Comment: Which `View` object are you trying to get to? the TabHost?

Comment: whatever view is the container of the tabindicator view

Comment: It looks like @Yoni Samlan's answer is probably what you are looking for then.